# Check :enabled state of $(this) element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, this, isenabled

Maybe I'm missing something and failing at google all at that same time but how would I say similar to:

```
...
if ($(this:enabled)){
    //some code
}
...
```

I know normally you'd say something like `$("#someID:enabled")` but how to use with `$(this)`?

Comment: how do you concatenate a string to a variable?

Comment: You mean `$(this).is(':enabled')`, right

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`is(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/is/#is-selector) method like this:

```
if ($(this).is(':enabled')) {
    // some code
}
```

Comment: Always great stuff here at SO. This is what I needed, thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this `$(":enabled", this)` the same as `$("option:selected", this)`?

Comment: @TimLewis - if you mean that `$(":enabled", this)` is the same as `$(this).find(":enabled")`, yes it is ?

Comment: @adeneo Ah ok, `.find` not `.is`. Thanks for that clarification.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
if($(this).is(':enabled'))
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a filtering method that you can use for this.

`if( $(this).is(':enabled') ) { 
    // do something here 
}`

http://api.jquery.com/is/